Find all links by regex
I want to check if an input text contains a link. My first idea was to do something like this:
\w+\.(?:com|net|org)(?:\W|$)

Part: com|net|org would contain all of the possible top level domains (about 1500). This works for theese examples:
there is a valid link https://www.example.com
there is a valid link www.example.net
there is a valid link example.org
there is no valid link example.organization

But would not work for this:
there is no valid link name@example.com

I don't want match emails. How can I repair this?
https://regex101.com/r/NXQzCp/2

Using what language?

I am using c#, but I guess I can adapt from regex101 solution

What about https://www.example.com/index.html?

I am interested only in domains, should have mention that

@derpirscher There's a difference between validating a string and searching for a substring.

What about country domains, like www.company.co.uk?

If you "forgot to mention" something you should use the Edit button to add it.

@Barmar If you have a regex, that is capable of validating if a string is a valid link, you can also use this regex to find matching substrings in a longer string. But as OP forgot to mention the "domain only" part it maybe doesn't matter anyways ...

@Barmar I edited my post

(?<!@)\b\w+\.(?:com|net|org)\b
you could add a negative lookbehind for the @ character and force a word boundary... and also use word boundary \b instead of (?:\W|$)
